# How to construct a <stdexcept> or <system_error> exception without throwing?

Tags: c++, exception, out-of-memory

Exceptions defined in `<stdexcept>` (e.g. `std::logic_error`, `std::runtime_error` and their subclasses such as `std::system_error`) have constructors expecting string arguments, e.g.:

```
domain_error(const string& what_arg);
domain_error(const char* what_arg);
```

with postconditions

```
strcmp(what(), what_arg.c_str()) == 0
strcmp(what(), what_arg) == 0
```

respectively. There is no requirement that these arguments passed to the constructors remain valid during the lifetime of these exceptions, so the only way to ensure that the postconditions hold, is to **duplicate** and store these dynamic strings. This requires memory, so I assume that their construction itself may throw `std::bad_alloc` or similar, which is usually **most unexpected**. This causes problems, because every code example I've seen in the wild encourages people to write code like

```
if (haveError)
    throw std::runtime_error("BOO!"); // May throw std::bad_alloc instead?!
```

whereas it would seem to be much safer to construct the exception beforehand in some other place, e.g:

```
struct A {
    // During allocation of A one would often expect std::bad_alloc anyway:
    A() : m_someException("BOO!") {}
    void f() {
        /* Do stuff */
        if (haveError)
            throw m_someException;
            /* Note that according to §18.8.1.2 all standard library
               classes deriving from `std::exception` must have publicly
               accessible copy constructors and copy assignment operators
               that do not exit with an exception. In implementations such
               exception instances most likely share the common string
               with all their copies. */
    }
    std::runtime_error const m_someException;
};
```

This makes me very cautious of libraries which throw any such exceptions, e.g even `regex_error` from `<regex>` in C++11!!!

**Why don't these exceptions have no-throw/noexcept constructors?** Does the C++ core guidelines have a say on this?

PS: Personally I would have left `what()` a pure abstract method at this point in the exception ancestry chain.

**EDIT 09.10.2017:** Here's a PoC demonstrating that `std::runtime_error` construction can throw a `std::bad_alloc` instead:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

bool throwOnAllocate = false;

void * operator new(std::size_t size) {
    if (!throwOnAllocate)
        if (void * const r = std::malloc(size))
            return r;
    throw std::bad_alloc();
}

void operator delete(void * ptr) { std::free(ptr); }

int main() {
    std::string const errorMessage("OH NOEZ! =(");
    throwOnAllocate = true;
    throw std::runtime_error(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Yes, its possible a function doesn't execute because of a shortage of unused heap memory at that instant, but displaying the error 'alert' actually freezes or crashes the system.  Thankfully , this is rare.

Comment: "whereas it would seem to be much safer to construct the exception beforehand in some other place" -- I don't get it. If your `throw std::runtime_error("BOO!");` would have thrown a different exception due to not enough memory being available, allocating the `std::runtime_error` beforehand would *still* require that memory to be available. The only change I see is that `bad_alloc` would be thrown earlier.

Comment: @hvd earlier in some better or **expected** context, e.g. `new A()`. It is terrible to have an exception **unexpectedly** being thrown **during** error/exception handling (C++11 exception nesting contexts included).

Comment: It is a wholeheckofalot more terrible if such a grave exception would *not* be thrown.  Don't sweat the small stuff, if bad_alloc is looming then it doesn't matter at all that it happens when you are about to throw, it will always happen and you'll never be happy about it.

Comment: I guess if you are concerned about the program to run under 100% error safe conditions, you shouldn't use stdexcept, but your own exceptions, which store pointers to c-strings, which were initialised with program startup or similar, where you can control the memory implications.

Comment: @scones That's what I'm mostly doing, but this means I can't use many libraries using the `<stdexcept>` exceptions, including the C++11 standard  `<regex>` due to `regex_error` inheriting from `runtime_error`...

Comment: I don't think you should bother with <regex> using runtime_error, after all regexes might and will allocate memory during their normal work too. If you want to handle OOM, you should not use standard regex'es at all or you should be prepared to handle those errors.

Comment: @OP Even if they had noexcept ctors -- it wouldn't have helped you. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497684/what-happens-if-throw-fails-to-allocate-memory-for-exception-object/45552806#45552806). I suggest simply expecting std::bad_alloc from *any* throw statement. It is easy to see why once you realize primary difference between exceptions and C-style EH -- latter has error object type mentioned in function signature and caller allocates required memory on stack. With exceptions you can't do that -- have to use some sort of "dynamic" allocation.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, it is **not possible** to construct any objects with an absolute guarantee of no exceptions.

You may consider allocating on the stack, but your thread stack could run out and will cause system error/exception. Your CPU may get an external interrupt, right when you throw, that system can't handle and everything gets fried. As others have suggested, don't fret the small stuff. Running out of memory is something most user programs can't recover from, so don't worry about it, elegantly fail. Don't try to handle every bad situation, just ones you can easily recover from.

As a side-note, for the situation about running out of memory, a lot of high graphics games do all of their heap allocation up-front during game initialization and try to avoid after the game starts to reduce running into issues with out of memory/slow allocations in the middle of a game (jittery game & bad user experience). You can similarly be smart about design of your program to reduce the chances of running into bad situations.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about pre-allocating memory. +1

Comment: It IS possible. Stack overflow is a very special case because unless you use recursive algorithms, your program will require fixed amount of stack space regardless of size of its input. With dynamic memory allocations this is different, as usually more input requires more memory to process it. Given input that is large enough most programs will encounter OOM.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot construct `std::logic_error` or `std::runtime_error` without ever getting `std::bad_alloc`, but most of the time it doesn't matter. If the operation can fail, separate code path has to be provided anyway to handle this, same code path can be used to handle `std::bad_alloc` as well. In those rare cases when it matters, you should just be derived from `std::exception` directly and make `what()` member function return a fixed string. Most of the time "function X throws Y", should be read as "function X throws Y and `std::bad_alloc`", unless explicitly stated otherwise. This also why C++11 discarded `throw()` specified in favor of `noexcept()`.

I don't find the up-front allocation of exceptions helpful, since if you are encountering `std::bad_alloc`, losing some error information at this point might be a good choice as such situations are rare and not worth the hassle. Calling code can just assume such function has failed due to memory allocation failure as part of its normal work.

Now if you are worried about losing error information because of exception is thrown during handling of another exception, you can try looking at exception chaining (or exception nesting). Examples of this can be found in other languages:

- Python has the best implementation of this and implements both explicit and implicit exception chaining: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/
- Java implements explicit and partially implicit chaining: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html (look for getCause() and getSuppressed())
- C# implements only explicit exception chaining: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx

C++11 provides standard way of nesting exceptions with `std::throw_with_nested()` and `std::rethrow_if_nested()`. Unfortunately, if you throw exception outside of `catch()` block, using `std::rethrow_if_nested()` later on that exception will terminate your program, so this facility IMO is kinda broken. If you really care about such issues, you can implement your own variant that can do both explicit and implicit chaining (you will need `std::current_exception()` to do this). You won't be able to force external libraries to use your facility, but at least your code can be very advanced in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (haveError)
    throw std::runtime_error("BOO!"); // May throw std::bad_alloc instead?!
```

by the time you reach this `throw` you should have already taken care of all clean up so in most cases, having a `std::bad_alloc` thrown instead of a `std::runtime_error` won't make much of a difference really.

The only exceptional case, I can thing of is when exceptions are used to control the flow of a program - I tend to do this very often with code such as:

```
try { 
  auto face = detectFace(); // may throw a custom no_face_exception or a many_faces_exception
  // do work with face
} 
catch (no_face_exception& e) {
  std::cout << "no face detected\n";
}
catch (many_faces_exception& e) {
  std::cout << "too many faces detected\n";
}
```

In this particular case failure to allocate memory would cause `detectFace` to throw a `std::bad_alloc` instead which would cause a disastrous crash. First allocating the exceptions before throwing, as you suggested, would not change anything at all - the program would still crash with a `std::bad_alloc` since the allocation would still fail. The only way around this problem would be to simply catch the `std::bad_alloc`:

```
catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
  std::cout << "bad alloc reported\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is true only if you are trying to use built-in exception types. 
Although what some other answers in this thread say, there *is* a difference between throwing and failing, and there *is* a difference between throwing different types of exceptions.

How can I say that? Because this is how the exceptions mechanism is built for.

Failing to allocate on the stack provide no easy recovery while failing to allocate on the heap just throws. There *is* a difference because there *is* a way to recover from heap failure.
In the same way, one can `catch` different exceptions because one might deal differently with them. There *is* such a mechanism because recovery might be very different.

Moreover, while `bad_alloc` might not be very common on most platforms and applications, it *is* something that one should take care of, especially in those cases where memory is small and/or application requires lots of it. And yes, recovery from `bad_alloc` might sometimes be very different than recovery from other issues, like database errors or connection issues. It is true, though, that if you get the `bad_alloc` when trying to allocate only enough room for a very short message, you are on a deep problem, but still there might be recovery option (e.g.: If you hold lots of data for caching purpose only, you might release them).

Nevertheless, **the solution is quite simple** - it is not a coincidence that the `what()` function of `std::exception` is virtual, and it returns the simplest type - `const char *`. You can inherit any exception you want directly from `std::exception`, and implement it in a way that does not allocate on the heap. For example, have the message as a static member of your class (possibly with some placeholders for values) or just provide it as a string literal. That way you can make sure that no new allocation is to be done upon throwing.